# Visual Studio Deploy Solution Version Number

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

Are there any hacks around the normal (and infuriating) Visual Studio Deploy Solution numbering system?

I have many assemblies I'm deploying with a Major.Minor.Build.Revision scheme for assembly versions. When I set the version for the setup.exe/Installer.exe, I can only do Major.Minor.Build. I'm not allow that fourth section for revision. This causes an issue because I key build numbers off date. So if my build is 906 for 09/06/11, I can only install (not uninstall and install, just install) once a day as it will see a previous version with the same version number and say a previous version is blocking install.

Besides using InstallShield (can't use this due to client requirements), are there any hacks to get the normal deploy solution to accept four part versions?

Comment: Erm, the Version property is the version number of the installer, not the application.  Pay attention to ProductCode, press F1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer ignores the fourth [Product Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859%28VS.85%29.aspx) field. So as long as you are using MSI packages, there's not much you can do. The old build needs to be manually uninstalled before installing a new build.